# Polymorphic join table and nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I don't know what's the best way to solve this problem and I'll appreciate your help.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. There is an `Act` model. And it has many `Organizations`.
2. An `Organization` can have many `Groups` and also, a `Group` can have many `Subgroups`.
3. The `Groups` are loaded dynamically depending on the selected `Organization`, and the `Subgroups` are also loaded depending on the selected `Group`.
4. An `Organization` could have a `Group` or not, and also a `Group` could have a `Subgroup`or not

Here you are a mock-up of what I have explained above:

- In the new `Act` form there is a section to add `Organizations`, something like this:

  [image]
- When you write an `Organization` it loads the options for the `Group` selector, and the same happens with a selected `Group` and the `Subgroup` selector:

  [image]
- When you click the add button, a new `Organization` section appears

  [image]
- A field can be empty. (This is a valid form)

  [image]

  - Also, If you want to edit the `Act`, the form should show the `Organizations` added before:

  [image]

I have this DB:

[image]

- `ActOrganizations` is a polymorphic table, and also a join table

My main problems are about the form: how to build it to retrieve and persist the data easily and how to retrieve the stored `Organizations` to show them in the edit form. (I'm using simple-form)
I tried many approaches, but they were not very elegant. I'd like to know the closest way to the "rails-way" to do this.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Share which way you are using and i can help you with issue with it. Plus a suggestion that you can use single-table-inheritance for organizations, groups and subgroups.

Comment: Is there any difference between a STI and a polymorphic table? I'm using the second one. My form is now empty, I tried with collection_select, but I don't know how to build the form.

Comment: Currently you have 3 different tables but in STI you will have 1 table & 3 models. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Is possible with STI to keep the functionality of an `Organization` has_many `Groups`? I have to look for information about STI to see if it could work.

Comment: yes it will work same as your current scenairio

Comment: After reading some articles, I think STI doesn't fit very well to my problem.